# URL routing within an Android application

Tags: android-intent, android-webview, android

I am using a webview with many types of links in my iOS application. The links point to a specific URL

```
appname/answers/1  -> load a view with answer 1
appname/questions/2/answer  -> load a view to answer question 2
```

Which i in turn specifies the action that the system should take to handle it

If I would like to reuse my webview in my android application, what would be the right way to handle it? ie:

- where do I place the routing code
- best technique to write the routing?

Comment: Can you please explain your requirement in terms of what you want in UI flow.It is not clear as what exactly you want.Kindly elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want this one, it's pretty handy for those of us with Three20/iOS background:
https://github.com/usepropeller/routable-android